# Django Like Button with AJAX Request

Tags: jquery, django, ajax

I'm trying to create an AJAX request in Django to update a Like Button.

I'm getting an Error from the AJAX call.  Not sure how to troubleshoot it.

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

[image]

**.script**

```
$(".vote-form").submit(function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          let poopfact_id = $(this).attr("id");
          const voteCount = $(`.voteCount${poopfact_id}`).text();
          let url = $(this).attr('action');
  $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: url,
            data: {
              'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
              'poopfact_id': poopfact_id,
            },
            
            success: function(response) {
              document.getElementById("vote_count").innerHtml = response['total_votes']
              console.log('success', response)
              
            },
            error: function(response) {
              console.log('error', response),
            },
          });
```

**.views**

```
def vote(request, poopfact_id):
    user = request.user
    post = get_object_or_404(PoopFact, id=poopfact_id)
    if request.method=="POST":
        if user.is_authenticated:
            if "upvote" in request.POST:
                if user in post.upvote.all():
                    post.upvote.remove(request.user)
                    total_votes = post.upvote.count() - post.downvote.count()
                    data = {"total_votes": total_votes}
                    return  JsonResponse(data, safe=False)
                else:
                    post.upvote.add(request.user)
                    post.downvote.remove(request.user)
                    total_votes = post.upvote.count() - post.downvote.count()
                    data = {"total_votes": total_votes}
                    return  JsonResponse(data, safe=False)
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('user_login'))
```

**.html**

```
<form action="{% url 'vote' poopfact.id %}" style="display: inline-block" method="POST" class="vote-form" id="{{poopfact.id}}">
  ... 
  <div class="voteCount{{poopfact.id}}" id="vote_count">{{   poopfact.total_votes }}</div>
  <button type="submit" name="upvote" class="btn btn-primary"><i   class="fa-solid fa-up-long"></i></i></button>
  ...
```

Comment: What's the output of your cmd or terminal when you receve error in console it is easy to debug if your server debug mode is on. Make use of network tab in browser to get actual response from server

Comment: Oh wow that Network Tab is so useful!  Thank you Ankit!  I got a ValueError it says didn't return an HttpResponse Object.  I think I need to pass the "upvote" in AJAX somehow.  Do you now how to do that by any chance?

Comment: Hello @kozendgray pass `upvote`  inside **AJAX** `data:{}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an alternative solution:

template body:

```
{% for fact in poopfacts %}
    <div id="{{ fact.id }}">{{ fact.total_votes}}</div>
    <button value="" onclick="addVote('{{ fact.id }}', 1)">+</button>
    <button value="" onclick="addVote('{{ fact.id }}', -1)">-</button>
    <hr>
{% endfor %}
```

.script:

```
<script>
    function addVote(id, vote) {
        let url = "{% url 'core:poop-facts-vote' %}";
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: url,
            data: {
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}',
            'id': id,
            'vote': vote,
            },
            success: function(response) {
                total_votes = response['votes'];
                poopfact_id = response['id'];
                e = document.getElementById(poopfact_id)
                e.innerHTML = total_votes;
                console.log('success', response);
            },
            error: function(response) {
                console.log('success', response);
            },
        });
    }
</script>
```

views.py:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
from core.models import PoopFact
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def poop_facts_vote(request):
    id = request.POST.get('id')
    vote = int(request.POST.get('vote'))

    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        poopfact = get_object_or_404(PoopFact, id=id)
        poopfact.total_votes += vote
        poopfact.save()
        poopfact.refresh_from_db()
        return JsonResponse({'votes': poopfact.total_votes, 'id': poopfact.id})

def poop_facts(request):
    poopfacts = PoopFact.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'poop_facts.html', {'poopfacts': poopfacts})
```

models.py

```
class PoopFact(models.Model):
    total_votes = models.IntegerField()
```

Adapting to you `upvote` / `downvote` model:

```
def poop_facts_vote(request):
    id = request.POST.get('id')
    vote = int(request.POST.get('vote'))

    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        poopfact = get_object_or_404(PoopFact, id=id)
        if vote > 0:
            # upvote
            ...
        else:
            # downvote
            ...

        return JsonResponse({'votes': poopfact.total_votes, 'id': poopfact.id})
```